# does wordpress auto update work without a cron job?

Tags: cron

I'm a bit on a loss here. Since WP 3.7 you can update your wordpress automatically. Since then it's more hit and miss on several servers here. I would like to understand, if it is enough to enable automatic updates [described here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates) and how this would work without a cron job.

I'm under the impression right now, that the upgrade is only started, when ever someone logs into the backend, is this correct? If so, is there a way to automate the updates via a cron job?

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of Wordpress will update automatically. AKA. you do absolutely nothing and then at random times you'll receive an email telling you it has self updated. This does not require any cronjobs etc. As for setting this up, it may or may not require FTP credentials (can't recall off the top of my head).

edit: auto update will only work if FTP credentials don't need to be entered manually.

Comment: And this doesn't seem to work reliably. I have on a shared host here 5 WP installations on 3.9.2 (the current current version) and 10 on 3.9.1 - all have the neccessary settings.

Also, without a cron job, how does the update gets started, I wonder..

Comment: Look it up. There are many things that will prevent the auto update from occuring, by design. AKA. if it's a git repo or other config is present etc.

Comment: I looked it up and didn't find a documentation that describes, what prevents auto updates. That's why I'm here. So if you could share your knowledge kindly, especially in regard to git repos preventing WP updates, as some of these installations are actually managed by git. thanks.